# I somehow deduced that $\tan x=\iota$ for any real value of $x$ by equating the value of $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$ obtained using two identities.

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

Let's assume that we're familiar with the identity : $\tan \Bigg (\dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg ) = -\cot x$ which we have derived using the *unit circle*.

I was trying to equate the values of $\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg )$ obtained using the above mentioned identity and the compound angle identity and I got a weird result. Have a look :

$$\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg ) = \dfrac{\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2} + \tan x}{1 - \tan \dfrac{\pi}{2} \tan x}$$
For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $\tan \dfrac{\pi}{2} = a$ and $\tan x = b$.
$$ \therefore \tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg ) = \dfrac{a + b}{1 - ab} \implies -\cot x = \dfrac{a + b}{1 - ab}$$
Also,
$$-\cot x = \dfrac{-1}{\tan x} = \dfrac{-1}{b}$$
$$ {\color{red} {\therefore \dfrac{-1}{b} = \dfrac{a + b}{1 - ab} \implies -1 + ab = ab + b^2 \implies -1 = b^2}}$$
This leads us to :
$$\tan x = b = \sqrt{-1} = \iota$$
which is not true.

So, what went wrong here?

I think that the ${\color{red}{\text{highlighted part}}}$ was wrong because while cross-multiplying, I automatically made the assumption that $1 - ab$ has a real value which won't be the case if $\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \Bigg )$ doesn't have a real value (which is actually the case as $\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \Bigg ) = \dfrac{\sin \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \Bigg )}{\cos \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \Bigg )} = \dfrac{1}{0}$ which does not have a real value and approaches $\infty$)

Was this the mistake I made?

Thanks!

Comment: An amusing thing to point out - the function $\tan:\Bbb C \setminus \{(n+\frac12)\pi : n \in \Bbb Z\}\to \Bbb C$ attains *every* complex value but $\pm \iota$(!) So, not only is "$\tan x = \iota$ for all $x$" wrong, it is about as far from being correct as one can get! :D

Comment: What does $\Bbb C \backslash {(n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi : n \in \Bbb Z}$ mean here?

Comment: The set of all complex numbers except odd multiples of $\pi/2$, i.e., the largest subset of $\Bbb C$ on which $\tan = \dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ can be defined.

Comment: I think I get it to some extent, but I'm still a lot confused as to why what I did didn't work out. I'm not used to such paradoxes.

Comment: My comment was not in any way related to answering your actual question. The short answer to that is: doing any manipulation by considering $a = \tan (\pi/2)$ is not "legal" since you treat $a$ as some real number when $\tan \pi/2$ is not even defined.

Comment: It kind of was related to proving that $\tan x = \iota$ is correct by no chance and that did help me, though. So, I did kind of make a mistake at the highlighted part but also made a mistake by doing operations on $a$, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cool "paradox," hadn't seen it before!

Even before the red line, the identity

$$\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg ) = \dfrac{\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2} + \tan x}{1 - \tan \dfrac{\pi}{2} \tan x}$$

is objectionable.

This isn't true-- or, more accurately, it isn't even grammatically correct, since $\frac{\pi}{2}$ isn't in the domain of the tangent function.

Similarly, when you let $a = \tan\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$ you are saying something grammatically incorrect, and so you can't expect to do formal algebraic manipulations with $a$ and receive something meaningful. It might be instructive to replace your identity with the identity

$$\tan \Bigg ( \dfrac{\pi}{2} + x \Bigg ) = \lim_{y \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\tan y + \tan x}{1 - \tan y \tan x}$$

(which is valid for any $x$ not an integer multiple of $\pi$), and see what happens.

Comment: So, this is basically evaluating $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$ using the compound angle identity is kind of like an exception? This sure is cool, but also messes with your head a lot.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Some maths are full of "exceptions", like this: $0·x=0·y \Rightarrow x=y$

Comment: @Ripi2 It's always interesting to discover them yourself :D Thanks!